# Beautiful Soup doesn't handle more than ~2700 lines of source code?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I'm currently trying to scrap the ATP (tennis association) website and i'm confronted to an issue that I am unable to solve.

When I try to scrap lines that are located after the line number 2700 i get an error.

Is there a way to solve this problem ?

Here is my code (this code works perfectly for the previous lines) :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen
import sys

BASE_URL = "http://www.atpworldtour.com/Share/Event-Draws.aspx?e=540&y=2012"

def make_soup(url):
    html = urlopen(url).read()
    return BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

def get_player_name_third_round_winner(section_url):
    soup = make_soup(section_url)
    colonne4 = soup.find("td", "col_4")
    playerWrap = colonne4.findAll("div", "playerWrap")
    for name in playerWrap:
        print name.find("a").string

def get_player_score_third_round_winner(section_url):
    soup = make_soup(section_url)
    colonne4 = soup.find("td", "col_4")
    scores = colonne4.findAll("div", "scores")
    for score in scores:
        print score.find("a").string

get_player_name_third_round_winner(BASE_URL)
get_player_score_third_round_winner(BASE_URL)
```

Here is the error displayed :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Me/Desktop/ATP/atp_col4", line 27, in <module>
    get_player_name_third_round_winner(BASE_URL)
  File "/Users/Me/Desktop/ATP/atp_col4", line 16, in get_player_name_third_round_winner
    playerWrap = colonne4.findAll("div", "playerWrap")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'
[Finished in 1.6s with exit code 1]
```

Comment: Your code works fine. http://asciinema.org/a/7539

Comment: I just tried it again and i'm still getting the same error i don't understand.

Comment: I tried your code several times: Sometimes it does work, and sometimes it produces the exception you posted. Therefore it seems the page at `BASE_URL` returns slightly different results for every request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have the same error with you. But I handle to make it print the results. I don't know if this is the best solution, but at least, it is one.

I changed the code to this one:

```
def make_soup(url):
   html = urlopen(url).read()
   return BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
```

and then I also include this part:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(30000)
```